# How can I add columns dynamically to a Spring Data JPA @Query

Tags: spring-data-jpa

Consider the following method on a Spring Data JPA interface:

```
@Query("select distinct :columnName from Item i")
List<Item> findByName(@Param("columnName") String columnName);
```

I would like to use such a method for performing queries dynamically using different column names on the same entity.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use QueryDSL support built into Spring Data.  See [this tutorial](http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) to get started.

Comment: Thank manish , I have checked it on Github for code reference, but still its not sufficient for my requirement, do you have any code link where I can refer this.

Comment: First use the linked tutorial to get familiar with the QueryDSL way of querying and make sure that you are getting expected results.  Then, use the QueryDSL class [PathBuilder](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.2.2/apidocs/com/mysema/query/types/path/PathBuilder.html) to generate queries dynamically using field names and field values.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You'll have to implement such a method [by yourself](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour). And you won't be able to use parameters: you'll have to use String concatenation or the criteria API. What you'll pass won't be a column name but a field/property name. And it won't return a `List<Item>`, since you only select one field.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must [implement custom Spring Data repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) by adding interface:

```
public interface ItemCustomRepository {

    List<Item> findBy(String columnName, String columnValue);

}
```

then you must extend your current Spring Data repository interface with newly created i.e.:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long>, ItemCustomRepository, QueryDslPredicateExecutor {

}
```

and then you must implement your interface using [Query DSL dynamic expression feature](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html/ch03.html#d0e2038) (the name ItemRepositoryImpl is crucial - it will let you use original Spring Data repository implementation):

```
public class ItemRepositoryImpl implements ItemCustomRepository {

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository itemRepository;

    public List<Item> findBy(final String columnName, final String columnValue) {
        Path<Item> item = Expressions.path(Item.class, "item");
        Path<String> itemColumnName = Expressions.path(String.class, item, columnName);
        Expression<String> itemValueExpression = Expressions.constant(columnValue);
        BooleanExpression fieldEqualsExpression = Expressions.predicate(Ops.EQ, itemColumnName, itemValueExpression);

        return itemRepository.findAll(fieldEqualsExpression);
    }

}
```