# Mapping JPA native query to DTO returns column name instead of column value

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a project using JPA and Spring Boot.

I have an `Entity` named (for example) Model:

This class is like this:

```java
private String model_id;
private String attr1;
private String attr2:
private String attr3;
```

I want to query according to `model_id` and one of these attributes.

So I've created this query in SQL and works using MySQL:

```sql
SELECT model_id AS modelId, attr1 AS attribute FROM my_table WHERE attribute LIKE '%my_value%'
```

So native query is:

```java
@Query(SELECT model_id AS modelId, :attribute AS myAttribute FROM my_table WHERE :attribute LIKE '%:filter%', nativeQuery=true)
List<MyModelDTO> doQuery(@Param("filter") String filter, @Param("attribute") String attribute)
```

And `MyModelDTO` is an interface like this:

```java
public interface MyModelDTO{
  String getModelId();
  String getMyAttribute();
}
```

But the desired output doesn't contains the correct value to `myAttribute` field. Is the column name instad the value.

For example, using this table:

```
| model_id |  attr1   |  attr2   |  attr3   |
---------------------------------------------
|  "id_1"  | "value1" | "value2" | "value3" |
---------------------------------------------
```

If I query using `filter=alue` and `attribute=attr2` expected result is:

```
{
  modelId: "id_1",
  myAttribute: "value2"
}
```

Because I'm looking a value that contains `alue` into `attr2` column.

But I get:

```
{
  modelId: "id_1",
  myAttribute: "attr2"
}
```

The column name is outpouted instead of column value.

Have I missing something using `nativeQuery` or trying to parse into DTO object?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your query will be interpreted as: `SELECT model_id AS modelId, 'attr2' AS myAttribute`

Comment: You might want to look to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554479/how-can-i-add-columns-dynamically-to-a-spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: Yes, thank you, I think that is the problem.