# Custom query with order by argument

Tags: spring, hibernate, sorting

I want to prepare custom query for getting sorted list of objectes from repository. I would like to have only one query, where I put only name of column as argument. What should I add after "Order by"?

```
@Query("FROM NoteEntity n where n.user.id = ?2 ORDER BY :columnName ASC")
List<NoteEntity> getNotesSortedByColumn(String columnName, String userID);
```

Following query return list of objects but without any sorting.

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47407043/spring-data-jpa-pass-column-name-and-value-as-parameters#48492077 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152468/how-to-add-custom-column-name-spring-data-jpa & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554479/how-can-i-add-columns-dynamically-to-a-spring-data-jpa-query

Comment: It has to look like `getNotesSortedByColumn(String userID, Pageable pageable)` where the `Pageable` is the Spring Data class so there's no explicit `order by` is even required. Also, you can use `Sort` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks for help.
I used "sort" to the custom query and everythingworks. In repository:

```
@Query("FROM NoteEntity n where n.user.id = ?1")
List<NoteEntity> getNotesSortedBy(String userID, Sort sort);
```

and in service:

```
List<NoteEntity> sortedNotes = noteEntityRepository.getNotesSortedBy(
            userID, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "columnName"));
```